# How to implement setOnItemLongClickListener(), to select a folder in the list view?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am using, `setonItemClickListener()` to select a file (and get its path in the edittext) at this time (means working).

I was trying hard to implement setOnItem**LongClickListener**() **to select folder** when long touch on folder to get its path.

Before it I was using, getparent() of the file choosed, to take the parent folder path to get the folder path in the edittext when the folder radio button is selected.

**Question:** How to implement setOnItemLongClickListener(), to select a folder in the list view?

Is it possible to give the functionality setonItemLongClickListener() for folder along with setonItemClickListener() for file or creation of all the code files for folder is also required, as for files?

**All answers are appreciated.**

Code files already working to get files, and folder path (by doing getparent() of the file) are:

MainFragment.java

```
    String curFileName;
    String filePath;
    EditText edittext;
    String AppendedForFullPath;

 edittext = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);  //Done for File Exploring, EditText, Browse Button.

        Button b1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.skipButton);   //Browse button
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(v.getContext(), FileChooser.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent1, REQUEST_PATH);
            }
        });

     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // See which child activity is calling us back.
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PATH) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                curFileName = data.getStringExtra("GetFileName");
                filePath = data.getStringExtra("GetPath");
                AppendedForFullPath = filePath + "/" + curFileName;
                edittext.setText(AppendedForFullPath);



                /*File file = new File(filePath);
                File parentDir = file.getParentFile(); // to get the parent dir
                String parentDirName = file.getParent(); // to get the parent dir name
                edittext.setText(parentDirName);*/
            }
        }
    }


    private List<File> getListFiles(File parentDir) {   //Used in algorithms to traverse files and subfolders.
        ArrayList<File> inFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
        File[] files = parentDir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Hello, I am a folder.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                inFiles.addAll(getListFiles(file));
            } else {
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Hello, I am a file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    inFiles.add(file);
                }
            }
        }
        return inFiles;
    }
```

FileChooser.java

```
/**
 * Created by hp on 01-06-2016.
 */

import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView; 

public class FileChooser extends ListActivity {

    private File currentDir;
    private FileArrayAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        currentDir=new File("/sdcard/");
        fill(currentDir); 
    }
    private void fill(File f)
    {
        File[]dirs=f.listFiles();
        this.setTitle("Current Dir: "+f.getName());
        List<Item>dir=new ArrayList<Item>();
        List<Item>fls=new ArrayList<Item>();
        try{
             for(File ff: dirs)
             { 
                Date lastModDate=new Date(ff.lastModified());
                DateFormat formater=DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
                String date_modify=formater.format(lastModDate);
                if(ff.isDirectory()){


                    File[] fbuf=ff.listFiles();
                    int buf=0;
                    if(fbuf != null){ 
                        buf=fbuf.length;
                    } 
                    else
                        buf=0;
                    String num_item=String.valueOf(buf);
                    if(buf == 0)
                        num_item=num_item+" item";
                    else
                        num_item=num_item+" items";

                    //String formated = lastModDate.toString();
                    dir.add(new Item(ff.getName(), num_item, date_modify, ff.getAbsolutePath(), "directory_icon"));
                }
                else
                {
                    fls.add(new Item(ff.getName(), ff.length()+" Byte", date_modify, ff.getAbsolutePath(), "file_icon"));
                }
             }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        Collections.sort(dir);
        Collections.sort(fls);
        dir.addAll(fls);
        if(!f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("sdcard"))
            dir.add(0, new Item("..", "Parent Directory", "", f.getParent(), "directory_up"));
        adapter=new FileArrayAdapter(FileChooser.this, R.layout.file_view, dir);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Item o = adapter.getItem(position);
        if(o.getImage().equalsIgnoreCase("directory_icon") || o.getImage().equalsIgnoreCase("directory_up"))
        {
            currentDir=new File(o.getPath());
            fill(currentDir);
        }
        else
        {
            onFileClick(o);
        }
    }
    private void onFileClick(Item o)
    {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Folder Clicked: "+ currentDir, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("GetPath", currentDir.toString());
        intent.putExtra("GetFileName", o.getName());

        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

FileArrayAdapter.java

```
import java.util.List; 

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView; 
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>{
    private Context c;
    private int id;
    private List<Item>items;

    public FileArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Item> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        c = context;
        id = textViewResourceId;
        items = objects;
    }
    public Item getItem(int i){
         return items.get(i);
    }
     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
               View v = convertView;
               if (v == null) {
                   LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                   v = vi.inflate(id, null);
               }

               /* create a new view of my layout and inflate it in the row */
            //convertView = ( RelativeLayout ) inflater.inflate( resource, null );

               final Item o = items.get(position);
               if (o != null) {
                       TextView t1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                       TextView t2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
                       TextView t3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextViewDate);
                       /* Take the ImageView from layout and set the city's image */
                        ImageView imageCity = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.fd_Icon1);
                        String uri = "drawable/" + o.getImage();
                        int imageResource = c.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, c.getPackageName());
                        Drawable image = c.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
                        imageCity.setImageDrawable(image);

                       if(t1 != null)
                        t1.setText(o.getName());
                       if(t2 != null)
                            t2.setText(o.getData());
                       if(t3 != null)
                            t3.setText(o.getDate());

               }
               return v;
     }
}
```

Item.java

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item>{
    private String name;
    private String data;
    private String date;
    private String path;
    private String image;

    public Item(String n,String d, String dt, String p, String img)
    {
        name = n;
        data = d;
        date = dt;
        path = p; 
        image = img;

    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public String getData()
    {
        return data;
    }
    public String getDate()
    {
        return date;
    }
    public String getPath()
    {
        return path;
    }
    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public int compareTo(Item o) {
        if(this.name != null)
            return this.name.toLowerCase().compareTo(o.getName().toLowerCase()); 
        else 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

file_view.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>-->
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fd_Icon1"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        />
    <TextView
        android:text="@+id/TextView01"
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fd_Icon1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        />
    <TextView
        android:text="@+id/TextView02"
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fd_Icon1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:text="@+id/TextViewDate"
        android:id="@+id/TextViewDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip">
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Both long and short clicks can work together.

Comment: Your XML is wrong, by the way. `android:text="@+id/TextView01"` is not a valid resource identifier for that field.

Comment: @cricket_007, can you please give some idea about that?